# Fetching first or latest first from many to many relationship in eager loading in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent, laravel-collection

I'm building a small application in `laravel 5.4`, where I'm having two models `Contact` and `Companies` I've many to many relationship between them, something like this in my **`Contact Model:`**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_contact','contact_id', 'company_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now at someplace I want to have current company i.e. I want to have `latest()` `first()`. Or `orderBy`, `created_by` `desc` and get `first()` row. For this I have to do something like this:

```
$contacts = Contact::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
    ->orWhereHas('company', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%');
    })
    ->with('company')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(50);
foreach ($contacts as $contact)
{
    $contact->company = $contact->company()->withPivot('created_at')->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc')->first();
}
```

For this to remove `foreach` I tried using a new relation in my `Contact` model:

```
public function currentCompany()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_contact','contact_id', 'company_id')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->first();
}
```

But while fetching in controller:

```
$contacts = Contact::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
    ->orWhereHas('currentCompany', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%');
    })
    ->with('CurrentCompany')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(50);
```

But it is throwing me error, is there any `eloquent` way or `Collection` way to remove this `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

use `first()` inside closure-

```
$contacts = Contact::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
->with(['company'=>function ($q) use($request) {
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')->first();
}])
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->paginate(50);
```

Or like this-

```
$contacts = Contact::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
->orWhereHas('company', function ($q) use($request) {
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%');
})
->with(['company'=>function($q){
       $q->first();  
}])
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->paginate(50);
```

this way you don't need to do any `additional foreach` loop.

Comment: While doing `$contact->company = $contact->company()->withPivot('created_at')->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc')->first();` I get an `json object` which is being placed at key value `company` of my collection, In your answer definitely I'm getting only one result but it is in form of `array`. Hope you get my point.

Comment: if you want json, then use `json_encode` to encode the `$contacts`

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do what you are trying to do directly. The relationships are query shortcuts. You can ensure you only get the first but that will still be a part of a collection if your relationship is one/many to many.

Consider this:

```
$contacts = Contact::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%')
    ->orWhereHas('company', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input. '%');
    })
    ->with([ 'company' => function ($query) {
            return $query->latest(); //Take the latest only 
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(50);
```

However to access the company you need to do something like `$contacts[index]->company->first()` because it will still produce a collection of related companies even.

The problem is the ORM will perform 2 queries, the first one will retrieve all the `Contact` models which fulfil the query and the 2nd one will retrieve all related models for all contacts it retrieved. This means if you do things like limiting it to 1 related result you might end up only getting one for all contacts retrieved.